# Equivalent Definitions of Total Variation of Complex Measure

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I was looking at complex measures, and specifically the total variation defined on them, and came across an interesting theorem that I found difficult to prove. In other books, the theorem is actually considered the definition of total variation of a complex measure, so I'm not sure how to show that it is equivalent to this. The definition we have is as follows:

If $\nu$ is a complex measure on a measure space $(X,\mathcal M)$ then

$$|\nu|(E):= \sup\left\{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|\nu(E_i)| : (E_1,\dots,E_n)\mbox{ is a partition of }E\right\}.$$

I want to show that if $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure such that $\nu\ll\mu$ then 
$\left(\frac{\mathrm d |\nu|}{\mathrm d  \mu} \right)= \left|\left(\frac{\mathrm d \nu}{\mathrm d\mu} \right)\right|\:\mu$ a.e

Comment: use radon-nikodym and jordan decomposition

Comment: Can you elaborate? What am I applying the Jordan decomposition to?